# how work with angular 2 and mvc5 together?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I have an mvc5 project working with angular. i implemented angular routing on my project and its working on without any problem

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component'

@NgModule({
   imports: [BrowserModule, 
        RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
                path: 'admin',
                component: AdminComponent
        }
    ])
],
declarations: [AppComponent,AdminComponent],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

now when i click on `<a routerLink="/admin">Heroes</a>` of my component template, my browser path will change to `"localhost/Admin"` and  i see `Admin component` template, inside `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`! ok  very good. but when i refreshed  the browser or when i copy the current address and paste it in address bar...i saw `HTTP 404. Error`.. for solving this problem i  created constrain for my `RouteConfig` !

i created this class:

```
     public class server_routes_constraint : IRouteConstraint
      {
        private readonly Func<Uri, bool> _per;

        public server_routes_constraint(Func<Uri, bool> per)
        {
          this._per = per;
        }
        bool IRouteConstraint.Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
          return this._per(httpContext.Request.Url);
        }
      }
```

and used it like t=what you see below in RoutConfig:

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

      routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
          constraints: new
          {
            serverRoute = new server_routes_constraint(url =>
            {
              return url.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("admin", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            })
          }
      );

      routes.MapRoute(
        name: "angular",
        url: "{*url}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }//
        );
    }
```

now every thing is working on and i can even refresh the page and use my angular route straightly. BUT!!!! :

my regular mvc routs not working! all of them will returning `/home/index` view.

**Update**: when i inserted this codes in my Route Config...All of `Html.ActionLinks` converts to html  like this: `<a href>Contact</a>`!!! but in 
normal style they should be like this : `<a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, you have done the configuration the other way round.

Looking at the registered routes in your `RegisterRoutes` method. You treat anything that starts with `admin` as server-side routing. Anything else will be redirected to `/Home/Index`.

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                // Set a constraint to only use this for routes identified as server-side routes
                constraints: new
                {
                    serverRoute = new ServerRouteConstraint(url =>
                    {
                    var serverSideRoutes = new String[] { "Settings", "Dashboard", "About" }; //these are whitelisted serverside routes
                    return serverSideRoutes.Any(route => url.PathAndQuery.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(route.ToLowerInvariant()));
                    })
                }
            );

            // This is a catch-all for when no other routes matched. Let the Angular 2 router take care of it
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "angular",
                url: "{*url}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // The view that bootstraps Angular 2
            );
        }
    }
```

With this configuration, the route engine will check if your route contains any of `serverSideRoutes`. If qualified, it will redirect to server side page or else it will move on to the next configuration which is configured for `angular` with wildcard `{*url}`

For example.

If you go to `http://localhost:61189/Settings` or `http://localhost:61189/Dashboard/Index` or `http://localhost:61189/About` in browser. All these paths being qualified server side routes, Route engine will redirect you to razer pages of respected controller/actions.

If you try to visit any other route than listed in `serverSideRoutes`, it will move on to next configuration and end up on Angular configuration.

Hope that clears the confusion.

Comment: hi...still have problem because all of Html.ActionLinks converts to html like this: <a href>Contact</a>!!! but in normal style they should be like this : <a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a> do you now why??? and when i enter path straightly...it will redirect to index

Comment: I hope you are putting @Html.ActionLink in razer page only.

Comment: What does it output? no href?